# ts return mistake type in not assignable to type

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
interface GetAmountProps {
  value: undefined | string
}

const getAmount = (value: GetAmountProps): string => {
  if (value === undefined) return '(0)';

  return value;
};

export default getAmount;
```

Why do I have an error on the line with `return value;`?

> Type 'GetAmountProps' is not assignable to type 'string'.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NdrQMW)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have it defined, a value of `value` would be:

```
{
  value: "banana"
}
```

Notice that this is any object with the property "value" of stype `string`

You probably meant

```
type GetAmountProps = undefined | string;
```

or

```
const getAmount = ({value}: GetAmountProps): string => {
  if (value === undefined) return '(0)';

  return value;
};
```

which is called like

```
getAmount({ value: "banana" });
```

Answer (score 0):

The function returns a `string`:

```
const getAmount = (...): string
```

For example, when it returns this string literal:

```
return '(0)'
```

But then you try to return the variable `value`:

```
return value;
```

Which is not a `string`:

```
(value: GetAmountProps)
```

Perhaps you meant to return its one property, which *is* a string?:

```
return value.value;
```

(As an aside... naming everything "value" is going to cause confusion.  Indeed, it already has.  You'll want to use more meaningful names.)